# autofill form fields for select boxes

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery.ajax form which populates data from the database and auto fills the form fields upon button click.
It works great when the form field is of type text
But it does not auto fill when the form field is a select box.
here is my code so far..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function myrequest(e) {
            var lead_id = $('#lead_id').val();
            $.ajax({
                 method: "GET",
                url: "/pdp/fetch-client-data/",
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    lead_id: lead_id
                },
                success: function( responseObject ) {
                    alert('success');
                    $('#client_name').val( responseObject.client_name );
                    $('#state').val(responseObject.state);

                },
                failure: function() 
                {
                    alert('fail');
                }
            });
        }

        $('#fetchFields').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            myrequest();
        });
        $("#lead_id").bind("change", function(e)
        {
          myrequest(); 
        });
    });

    </script>

    <table width="600" align ='center'>
    <form action ='<?php echo $SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>' method='post'>

        <tr>
            <td>        
                <label for="lead_id">Lead id: </label>

                <input type="text" name="lead_id" id="lead_id">

                <button id="fetchFields">Fetch</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Agent: <select name="agent">
                    <option value="">[Select]</option>
                    <?php foreach($this->agent_query as $agent){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $agent['id']; ?>"><?php echo $agent['name'];?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="client_name">Client Name:  </label>
                <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>
                <label for="state">State: </label>
                <select name="state" id='state'>
                <option id='state' value='1'></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>
                # of Policies: 
                <select name="policies">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="NEXT" name="submit">
            </td>
        </tr>

    </form>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say

> But it does not auto fill when the form field is a select box

Do you mean to fill the `<select>` with a list of data from server-side or to select an `<option>` that is already on the `<select>`?

If your case is that you want to fill the `<select>` then you have to create each node that represents each `<option>` filled with its corresponding array item that you brought from server-side. Ex.

```
$('#state>option').remove();
$.ajax(
  ...
  success: function(data){
    for(var i=0; i<data.array.length; i++){
      $('#state').append($('<option>')
        .attr('value', data.array[i].value)
        .html(data.array[i].name));
    }
  }
);
```

If what you want is to select an `<option>` that is already on your `<select>` then you need to iterate over your current options and either apply it the 'selected' attribute or set the `<select>`'s selectedIndex as the index of the option you want to select. For example:

```
$.ajax(
  ...
  success: function(data){
    $('#state>option>option').each(function(i, elm){
      if($(elm).attr('value').indexOf(data.state) >= 0){
        $(elm(.attr('selected', 'selected');
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: what i mean is the select option has already values like TX,NY and so on..When click on the fetch button, the query returns TX(for eg), then the selected option should automatically be TX. I ll try ur above code as i am still  new to jquery ajax

Comment: One last question though..if the query returns empty results? How do i display an error message in the form area? For eg. lead_id not found.

Comment: In your sample code, the lead_id is a value that you already have in your page, what you get from jQuery are the client_name and the array of states but if what you want is to know if the jQuery response data(responseObject in your sample) has returned at least one value then you should make your server-side json response capable of returning result code and result description and show a message in a div if the result code is an error code.